# CKEditor Placeholder Plugin Version

Tags: ckeditor, nuget, placeholder

I am using CKEditor v4.4.4. I wish to make my CKEditor to have display the placeholder tool bar as this page: http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/placeholder.html (double square brackets with yellow background). However, my placeholder looks like below (rounded-rectagle with fixed text):

[screen shot http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~lei200/image/editor.png](http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~lei200/image/editor.png)

I also notice there is an empty icon in the insert tool bar group beside the image tool bar button. I think I must miss something, but still get stuck. Any suggestion will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without knowing your setup - how did you end up with CKEditor 4.4.4? Which package did you download? Was it a clean install or an update? How did you install the Placeholder plugin? Did you clean your browser cache after upgrading? Is this a standalone CKEditor installation or some CMS/blog platform etc.?

Please note that Placeholder is an optional plugin (which comes with some dependencies), so it is best to install it through [CKBuilder](http://ckeditor.com/builder), as described in the [installation instructions](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_widget_installation). In any case, you need to add it to your build, because it is not included in any of the official distributions.

Last but not least, the Placeholder plugin was rewritten as a widget in CKEditor 4.3. Just check whether you are not using the previous, non-widget version for some reason.

Comment: Thanks, Anna. I got the ckeditor-full version 4.4.4 through Nuget. I can see there is a placeholder folder under my ckeditor\plugins directory and there are two files in it (placeholder.css and plugin.js). I set up my ckeditor like this:

CKEDITOR.replace('editorId', {
                    extraPlugins: 'placeholder'
});